# Network in Network using keras

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, keras

I want to implement **NiN** using **keras** but I could not found useful in net. I want to implement below **image architecture**. anybody can help??

[image: image architecture]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is there anything special about these N layers? Are they the same layer repeated? Is there a special reason to separate them? Etc.

Comment: I have network with 3 conv layer and 3 pooling layer. I want to create NIN, that is two networks which are series with each other to show result for accuracy. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the functional API of Keras (https://keras.io/models/model/) and do something like this:

```
def build_model(input_layer, idx):
     # model code (logits = first_layer(parameters)(input_layer)
     # could also load an already trained model.
     return logits

input_layer = Input(...) 
output = input_layer 
for i in range(num_models):
     output = build_model(output , i)
final_layer = Model(input_layer, output)
```